# How to revert back discarded changes in git?

Tags: git, github

I have added new files and made changes in branch I was working, created new branch and took all changes to the new one without commit. Came back to the branch I had worked and discarded all changes and found out that it affected on the new created branch and all changes are lost.

how can I revert them back?

Comment: What are the exact commands you used?

Comment: discarded changes are not committed - restore from another backup

Comment: Uncommitted changes do _not_ belong to any branch, they only live in your working tree. If you remove them from your working tree, they are lost. Restore from backup.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately your changes are probably lost.

If you are really lucky your IDE might allow you to Ctrl-Z back your code.

One the bright side writing the code a second time will make it better!